# How to remove rows where columns satisfy certain condition in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(1:10, sample(c(1:5), 10, replace=TRUE)))
# in real case the columns could be more than two
# and the column name could be anything.
```

What I want to do is to remove all rows where the value of all its columns
is smaller than 5. 
What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[!apply(df,1,function(x)all(x<5)),]
```

Comment: Thanks, but your method remove all columns where `at least one` column is less than 5. In my OP, `all columns` need to satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 1):

First of all ...please stop using `cbind` to create data.frames. You will be sorry if you continue. R will punish you.

```
df[ !rowSums(df <5) == length(df), ]
```

(The length() function returns the number of columns in a dataframe.)

Comment: +1 for the `cbind` advise. I think it's actually a `!=`. He wants to remove those rows, not keep them.

Comment: It's a NOT, and I guess it could also be a `!=`. Fixed

Comment: Isn't `(A!=B)` the same as `!(A==B)`? :-)

Comment: I first thought NO and then I reversed myself.